# What happens when a reference point to an object of a pointer (object in the heap) when the reference scope end?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What happens when a reference point to an object of a pointer (object in the heap) when the reference scope end? I mean is the object in the heap is destroy or it remains:

e.g:

```
void f(){
    Object &obj= *new Object() ;

   int &i = new int;
}

void main(){
  f();
}
```

the objects are destroy at the end of f or must be call "delete &n" at the end? the same for primitive values?
if it must be destroy then how I can create a copy of a constant primitive value and asigned to a referenced without make it with a "new"?

(sorry for the grammar or ortography, and the typing error from the original question)

Comment: You seem to mix your references with your pointers.

Comment: Your code sample will not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object &n = new Object();
```

This will not compile. A *new-expression* like `new Object()` returns a pointer to the dynamically allocated object. You can't initialize an `Object&` with an `Object*`.

If you have a reference of type `T&`, you should be initializing it with objects of type `T`. That's how a reference works. `T&` is a reference to a `T` object.

You *could* do this:

```
Object &n = *new Object();
```

This will dereference the pointer returned by the *new-expression* (with `*`) to get you the `Object` it points at and then initializes the reference with that `Object`. However, I don't recommend doing this at all. It just hides the fact that the object was allocated dynamically.

And no, doing this does not effect the lifetime of the dynamically allocated object. If you create an object with a *new-expression*, it has dynamic storage duration, so you have to `delete` it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to decide. You want this:

```
Object &n = * new Object();
```

Or you want this:

```
Object* &n = new Object();
```

Anyway, when the references go out of the scope, they not cause the object to be deleted.
In your example you will have memory leak, with no way to recover the `Object` and the `int` alocated in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: your code will not compile.

At most you should do (just for compile...):

`Object &n = *(new Object());` but I don't recommend this kind of practice.

Regarding the second question: ALWAYS you write "new", ALWAYS you must delete in some time.